# Video capture on Phonegap (3.5.0) doesn't work

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins, video-capture

As the title says I want to capture a video with Phonegap. I'm doing it on Nexus 5, Android 4.4.2 .

While the camera works, with the following code camera app (with no option for video) is launched:

```
   navigator.camera.getPicture(videoOnSuccess,videoOnError, { quality: 50,
        destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
        mediaType: Camera.MediaType.VIDEO
   });
```

Thanks in advance